# Empty the pagestyle for last parts of my report document

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, chapters, patching, pagestyle

I have patched in my preamble the command \chapter with the package `etoolbox` so as to get a defined style for all my chapters `\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{mystyle}{}{}`. (I am using the `fancyhdr` package )

At the end of my report document, I have a bibliography part and some `\chapter*` parts.

I would like to switch back to empty the headers from the bibliography part until the end of the document.

I tried to patch it the other way but I think it makes no sense. I tried also the simple command `\pagestyle{empty}` just before the `\bibliography` but it does not work.

EDIT : I add a simplified MWE

I noticed that if I remove the `caption` package, the bibliography and \chapter* style are gone... but there is not the headline...

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{lipsum,mwe}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
        \definecolor{BleuChapitre}{RGB}{0,76,153}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
        \bibliographystyle{apacite}

%%% defining "monstyle" pagestyle %%%

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
        \fancypagestyle{monstyle}{
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[LO]{\footnotesize\scshape\leftmark}
        \fancyhead[RO]{\footnotesize\rightmark}
        \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}}

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{monstyle}{}{}
    \renewcommand{\thechapter}{}

    %%% To remove extra space before and after chatper %%%

    \makeatletter
        \renewcommand*\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
    %       \vspace*{50\p@}%
            {%
                \parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont
    %           \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
    %               \huge\bfseries\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par
    %               \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
    %           \fi
    %           \interlinepenalty\@M
                \Huge\bfseries\color{BleuChapitre}
                #1\par
                \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
            }
        }
        \renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
    %       \vspace*{50\p@}%
            {%
                \parindent\z@\raggedright\normalfont
    %           \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
    %               \huge\bfseries\@chapapp\space\thechapter\par
    %               \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
    %           \fi
    %           \interlinepenalty\@M
                \Huge\bfseries\color{BleuChapitre}
                #1\par
                \nobreak\vskip 20\p@
            }
        }
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

        \afterpage{\blankpage}
        \pagestyle{monstyle}
        \doublespacing

    \chapter{First chapter}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \newpage\pagenumbering{gobble}

    \renewcommand\bibname{Bibliographie}
    \singlespacing
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{monstyle}{empty}{}{} %%% does not change anything
    \bibliography{references.bib}

    \newpage
    \chapter*{Annexes}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\pagestyle{empty}` doesn't work because the bibliography environment uses a chapter heading which in itself resets the page style to "mystyle". You need to redefine/alter the bibliography macro to change that. Try using the patchcmd macro right before the bibliography. Otherwise we would need a MWE to recreate your problem.

Comment: I am going to add this right now